# Nuget pull source code from my fork

Tags: c#, nuget

It is my first time to use nuget.
I fork a github project, applied my own changes. How do I let Nuget pull my source code, not origin one?

Thanks

Comment: You fork a GitHub project... (I assume that you are not the owner of that project) why don't you submit a Pull request with your changes, that way everyone benefits from your changes, and later the owner will push to Nuget.

Comment: Most author ignore my request :)

Comment: In that case it could be because the project has been abandoned, and you might have to rename it and create your own...

Comment: Can you post a link to the GitHub project in question?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is to take over someone else's project, for obvious reasons that is not allowed. You must be invited:
https://blog.nuget.org/20130205/managing-package-owners.html

If the GitHub project has been abandoned and the owner is not responding. What you can do is [contact github suppor](https://github.com/contact)t ask them to detach your fork, then rename the project and create your own Nuget package.

I will strongly recommend [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/pricing/) it is free for OpenSource projects and very easy to configure, it can build your project run your UnitTest and deploy to [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) or to [Myget](https://www.myget.org/)